# Sort array four times with different weighting in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

I want to sort an array four times, each time the sort-array-button is pressed a different status should be on top.

```
0: {id: 1, status: "danger"}
1: {id: 2, status: "danger"}
3: {id: 3, status: "red"}
4: {id: 4, status: "red"}
5: {id: 5, status: "yellow"}
6: {id: 6, status: "yellow"}
7: {id: 7, status: "green"}
```

First click on the sort button:
`danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow, green`
second press:
`red, red, yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger`
third press:
`yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger, red, red`
fourth press:
`green, danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow`
and with the fifth press you are back to the first sort again
`danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow, green`

Normally I sort arrays like this:

```
myArray.sort((x, y) => x.status < y.status ? -1 : 1);
```

How can I extend the sort to give a color a higher value to make this work again?

Comment: you should add priority property in your json

Comment: *"Normally I sort arrays like this"* That's incorrect. You need to return `0` when `x.status` and `y.status` are the same. For strings: `(x, y) => x.status.localeCompare(y.status)`. For numbers: `(x, y) => x.status - y.status`.

Comment: @Aman Kumayu I can't edit the json.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder good to know! I'll update my code. Any idea also for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally I sort arrays like this

First we have to fix that. :-) You need to return `0` when `x.status` and `y.status` are the same. In general, for strings it's `(x, y) => x.status.localeCompare(y.status)` and for numbers it's `(x, y) => x.status - y.status` (reverse `x` and `y` to switch from ascending to descending).

In your case, you want to assign values to the `status` types, and those values differ based on the click (apparently). To do that, give yourself mappings of status->number that you can pick based on what click it is:

```
const sortStyles = [
    {
        danger: 0,
        red: 1,
        yellow: 2,
        green: 3,
    },
    {
        red: 0,
        yellow: 1,
        green: 2,
        danger: 3,
    },
    {
        yellow: 0,
        green: 1,
        danger: 2,
        red: 3,
    },
    {
        green: 0,
        danger: 1,
        red: 2,
        yellow: 3,
    }
];
```

Then the sort is:

```
const style = sortStyles[index]; // index = 0 for first click, 1 for second, etc.
data.sort((x, y) => style[x.status] - style[y.status]));
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, status: "danger"},
    {id: 2, status: "danger"},
    {id: 3, status: "red"},
    {id: 4, status: "red"},
    {id: 5, status: "yellow"},
    {id: 6, status: "yellow"},
    {id: 7, status: "green"}
];

const sortStyles = [
    {
        danger: 0,
        red: 1,
        yellow: 2,
        green: 3,
    },
    {
        red: 0,
        yellow: 1,
        green: 2,
        danger: 3,
    },
    {
        yellow: 0,
        green: 1,
        danger: 2,
        red: 3,
    },
    {
        green: 0,
        danger: 1,
        red: 2,
        yellow: 3,
    }
];

example("First click, sortStyles[0]:", data, sortStyles[0]);
example("Second click, sortStyles[1]:", data, sortStyles[1]);
example("Third click, sortStyles[2]:", data, sortStyles[2]);
example("Fourth click, sortStyles[3]:", data, sortStyles[3]);

function example(label, data, style) {
    console.log(label);
    console.log(data.slice().sort((x, y) => style[x.status] - style[y.status]));
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks so much for your help!
And I will never use that bad sorting thing again ;)

Comment: @JanBürger - You are **far** from the first person to make that mistake. :-) Glad that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually (and not paying much attention to performance), you need to define an order for your `status` properties, and then rotate that order.  You could do it like this:

```
let order = ["danger", "red", "yellow", "green"];

function click() {
  order.push(order.shift()!)
  myArray.sort((x, y) => order.indexOf(x.status) - order.indexOf(y.status))
}
```

So when you call `click()`, the `order` array will take the first element off the list and push it onto the end.  And then you sort `myArray` based on the location of its `status` property in `order` (and if you are missing a status in `order` you can expect those to appear at the very front of the list no matter what; not sure what you want to do about edge cases like this, but you can handle them).

This gives the following behavior for this code:

```
function show() {
  console.log(myArray.map(x => x.status).join(", "))
}

show();
for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  console.log("CLICK");
  click();
  show();
}
```

Console log:

```
danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow, green 
CLICK 
red, red, yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger 
CLICK 
yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger, red, red 
CLICK 
green, danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow 
CLICK 
danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow, green 
CLICK 
red, red, yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger 
CLICK 
yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger, red, red 
CLICK 
green, danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow 
CLICK 
danger, danger, red, red, yellow, yellow, green 
CLICK 
red, red, yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger 
CLICK 
yellow, yellow, green, danger, danger, red, red
```

Looks like what you want.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoDeMAlgCYBcMAjADQzTpQCuElARKemAOYCmKbGAF86RMpQBMdBs1YwOXPgOE0AUGIowAzNKiMW7FL1KCRMDZQAsu-XLZGTK9SU0BWG7PYJeAGx8gAd1NRF0oANg8DeW8-QODncRgAdki7biNeMFMAXQBuVVUfXlgQFFJ+HHwFHn42OntjOujffyD69N5MtjzVADMmMGAoYnB6AAtAgAoASnNVGBhQSBAigDp-bknEVAwEVbh0AAdJgA8cAD4YE9WZFmnVgCsQYjBJprZp6dUhPoGhkbAix8xGAAGsZnMFqVyihVocWGNJtD+DcxsRelAZgBCL4LbZoTA3UqY050BCzbCXZGwl7lE4AeV6pxuelkswAtDBqatabwGUy9rcIJ9vgUIBMAjN8r1SjBJkVYGdcAAGXJXGAAHmoqquAGpdbMCPNFuAICteOsQJs2ABhAAyAEkbQBpD75BbAYFgqXG8VTab5H4FIA)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. This is the working solution I'm using now.

```
let sortStyle = {};
    switch (this.sortStatus) {
      case ('none'):
        sortStyle = {alert: 0, red: 1, yellow: 2, green: 3};
        this.myArray.sort((x, y) => sortStyle[x.status] - sortStyle[y.status]);
        this.sortStatus= 'alert';
        break;
      case ('alert'):
        sortStyle = {red: 0, yellow: 1, green: 2, alert: 3};
        this.myArray.sort((x, y) => sortStyle[x.status] - sortStyle[y.status]);
        this.myArray= 'red';
        break;
      case ('red'):
        sortStyle = {yellow: 0, green: 1, alert: 2, red: 3};
        this.myArray.sort((x, y) => sortStyle[x.status] - sortStyle[y.status]);
        this.sortStatus = 'yellow';
        break;
      case ('yellow'):
        sortStyle = {green: 0, alert: 1, red: 2, yellow: 3};
        this.myArray.sort((x, y) => sortStyle[x.status] - sortStyle[y.status]);
        this.sortStatus= 'green';
        break;
      case ('green'):
        sortStyle = {alert: 0, red: 1, yellow: 2, green: 3};
        this.myArray.sort((x, y) => sortStyle[x.status] - sortStyle[y.status]);
        this.sortStatus= 'alert';
        break;
      default:
        console.log('Error');
        break;
    }
  }
```